# FAILED: ninja: 'vendor/google/taimen.... when build lineageOS 17.1

Tags: android, lineageos

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
LINEAGE_VERSION=17.1-20211116-UNOFFICIAL-taimen
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_taimen
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a73
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a73
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.13.0-21-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-21.10
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QQ3A.200805.001
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/google/wahoo vendor/google/camera hardware/google/pixel vendor/google/taimen
============================================
wildcard(out/target/product/taimen/clean_steps.mk) was changed, regenerating...
FAILED: ninja: 'vendor/google/taimen/proprietary/etc/permissions/com.android.vzwomatrigger.xml', needed by 'out/target/product/taimen/system/etc/permissions/com.android.vzwomatrigger.xml', missing and no 
known rule to make it
00:04:45 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:28 (mm:ss)) ####
```

[failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clhER.png)

I am trying to to build lineageOS 17.1 for my device pixel 2XL, I did everything mention in official [lineageOS build guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/taimen/build) for my device. But at the building step i encounter above error, English is not my main language but i hope you guys can understand this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe lose something , should clone from github: https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_google/tree/lineage-17.1

Comment: Answer is very unclear and leads to many possible answers which may or may not work

Comment: sorry, it just useful for me, I don't know it is useful for everyone or not .